# Scene2d Image won't scale

Tags: java, action, libgdx, scaling

I am starting to learn libgdx and with it scene2d, but I have been having trouble with my splashScreen. My fade actions work perfectly, but the Image isn't being scaled (even when I add a Scaling to the constructor)...

I have a Texture splashTexture loaded from a png 512x512, of which the real image is 512x256, so I create a TextureRegion.
All of this is done in my show method:

```
@Override
    public void show() {
    super.show(); //sets inputprocessor to stage

    splashTexture = new Texture(SPLASHADR);

    // set the linear texture filter to improve the stretching
    splashTexture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
    splashTextureRegion = new TextureRegion(splashTexture, 0, 0, 512, 256);

}
```

Then comes the following in my resize method:

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    stage.clear();
    Drawable splashTextureDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(
            splashTextureRegion);

    Image splashImg = new Image(splashTextureDrawable);

    splashImg.getColor().a = 0f;
    splashImg.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.fadeIn(0.5f),
            Actions.delay(2f), Actions.fadeOut(0.5f)));

    stage.addActor(splashImg);

}
```

These are functions in a class SplashScreen which extends an AbstractScreen class (which actually has the render function):

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    stage.act(delta);

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.draw();
}
```

Any ideas are welcome, I've been looking through the javadocs for ages and haven't found a solution yet!

Thank you,

bnunamak

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out `stage.setViewport(float width, float height, boolean keepAspectRatio)`. It sounds like you want the image to fill the screen, so set the stage's viewport width/height to your image's width/height:

```
stage.setViewport(512, 256, false);
```

See the [scene2d wiki article](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d#viewport) for an explanation of the `keepAspectRatio` parameter:

> setViewport has a parameter named keepAspectRatio which only has an
>   effect when the stage size and viewport size aspect ratio differ. If
>   false, the stage is stretched to fill the viewport, which may distort
>   the aspect ratio. If true, the stage is first scaled to fit the
>   viewport in the longest dimension. Next the shorter dimension is
>   lengthened to fill the viewport, which keeps the aspect ratio from
>   changing.

If that wasn't exactly what you wanted, the article has a few different examples which should cover what you need.